# C# regex struggling

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
string text = "AT + CMGL =\"REC UNREAD\"\r\r\n+CMGL: 5,\"REC UNREAD\",\"+420733505479\",\"\",\"2015/09/08 13:38:31+08\"\r\nPrdel\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";
Regex regex = new REgex(CMGL:\s(.*?),\\"(.*?)\\",\\"(.*?)\\",\\"\\",\\"(.*?)\\"\\r\\n(.*?)\\r\\n\\r\\n);
```

I need output like this:

1. [38-39] `5`
2. [42-52] `REC UNREAD`
3. [57-70] `+420733505479`
4. [80-102]    `2015/09/08 13:38:31+08`
5. [108-113]   `Prdel`

I tried this expression on https://regex101.com and it seems all right but when I run my program, regex fails to find the text. I was only able to force it to find:

+CMGL: 5,

"REC UNREAD",

"+420733505479",

"",

"2015/09/08 13:38:31+08"

Prdel

```
I have absolutely no idea how this could happen. Could anyone help me please?
```

Comment: There are different flavors of regular expressions.  When testing make sure you use one that specifically uses the .Net regular expression engine.  Right now you're using one that only does php, javascript , and python.

Comment: Your given code seems wrong, especially this part: `new REgex(CMGL:\s`. could you correct it?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it should be CMGL:\\s(.*?),\\"(.*?)\\",\\"(.*?)\\",\\"\\",\\"(.*?)\\"\\r\\n(.*?)\\r\\n\\r\\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
CMGL: (?<num>\d+),"(?<rec>[^"]*)","(?<phone>[^"]*)","[^"]*","(?<date>[^"]*)"\s*(?<badword>.+)
```

See [demo at the .NET-compliant regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=CMGL%3a+(%3f%3cnum%3e%5cd%2b)%2c%22(%3f%3crec%3e%5b%5e%22%5d*)%22%2c%22(%3f%3cphone%3e%5b%5e%22%5d*)%22%2c%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%2c%22(%3f%3cdate%3e%5b%5e%22%5d*)%22%5cs*(%3f%3cbadword%3e.%2b)&i=AT+%2b+CMGL+%3d%22REC+UNREAD%22%0d%0a%0d%0a%2bCMGL%3a+5%2c%22REC+UNREAD%22%2c%22%2b420733505479%22%2c%22%22%2c%222015%2f09%2f08+13%3a38%3a31%2b08%22%0d%0aPrdel%0d%0a%0d%0aOK%0d%0a)

Results:

[image]

C#:

```
string text2 = "AT + CMGL =\"REC UNREAD\"\r\r\n+CMGL: 5,\"REC UNREAD\",\"+420733505479\",\"\",\"2015/09/08 13:38:31+08\"\r\nPrdel\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";
Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"CMGL: (?<num>\d+),""(?<rec>[^""]*)"",""(?<phone>[^""]*)"",""[^""]*"",""(?<date>[^""]*)""\s*(?<badword>.+)");
Match match2 = regex2.Match(text2);
if (match2.Success)
{
     Console.WriteLine(match2.Groups["num"].Value);
     Console.WriteLine(match2.Groups["rec"].Value);
     Console.WriteLine(match2.Groups["phone"].Value);
     Console.WriteLine(match2.Groups["date"].Value);
     Console.WriteLine(match2.Groups["badword"].Value);
 }
```